# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/vertx/sqlclient/impl/SqlConnectionImpl

Tags: maven, vert.x, mysql-connector, noclassdeffounderror

I have simplified my code until finding that I am doing something wrong when trying to connect this vertx application to mysql database, but I can not figure out what.

I have tried this simple code:

```java
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Promise;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLConnectOptions;
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLPool;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.PoolOptions;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.Row;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.RowSet;

public class MainApplication extends AbstractVerticle {

    public static MySQLPool mySqlClient;

    public void start(Promise<Void> start) {
        MySQLConnectOptions connectOptions = new MySQLConnectOptions()
            .setPort(******)
            .setHost(******)
            .setDatabase(******)
            .setUser(******)
            .setPassword(******);

        PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(5);

    mySqlClient = MySQLPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions);

    }

}
```

The problem takes place in the last line, and displays the error:

SEVERE: Failed in deploying verticle
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/vertx/sqlclient/impl/SqlConnectionImpl

I tried if it was something related to the dependencies, or to the database but I don't find anything related to this log.

Comment: This looks like a classpath problem. Make sure your Java app is launched with the vertx-sql-client JAR and vertx-mysql-client JAR in the classpath.